Flowable dynamic data source
I have already implemented the function of a dynamic data source using "DynamicRoutingDatasource extensions AbstractRoutingDatasource" in conjunction with "ThreadLocal" in my project. Now I want to integrate flowable, where the data source can be dynamically switched but cannot be dynamically switched to "SpringProcessEngine Configuration"。
@Bean
public SpringProcessEngineConfiguration springProcessEngineConfiguration() {
    SpringProcessEngineConfiguration configuration = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();
    configuration.setDataSource(dynamicRoutingDataSource);
    configuration.setDatabaseType("mysql");
    configuration.setAsyncExecutorActivate(false);
    configuration.setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_TRUE);
    return configuration;
}

